# Automically Register Unit Tests in C

Tags: c, unit-testing

Consider this minimal framework for running unit tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST(name) int test_##name()
#define RUN_TEST(name) \
    do {printf("%s\t%s\n", #name, test_##name() ? "OK" : "FAIL");} while(0)
#define ASSERT_EQ(left, right) \
    do {return (left) == (right);} while(0)

TEST(addition) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1 + 2, 3);
}

TEST(mult_fail) {
    ASSERT_EQ(42, 6 * 9);
}

int main() {
    RUN_TEST(addition);
    RUN_TEST(mult_fail);
}
```

It is used like so:

```
> gcc test_runner.c && ./a.out
addition        OK
mult_fail       FAIL
```

How can it be made so that the TEST macro automatically registers the tests? I want the main function to contain a single RUN_ALL_TESTS statement without having to refer to all the tests by name.

I know this can easily be done in C++, but I would prefer to see a purely C solution.

Comment: Make the `TEST` macro also add the function pointer into some global function pointers array. Then make `RUN_ALL_TESTS` to iterate that array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't believe what you're suggesting is possible in C without using any extensions. There is no way to run code before the main function which makes it impossible to add the function pointer to an array. However, it is possible in C++ because constructors can run before main.

Comment: Oh, I've started to write an answer based on this suggestion and got an almost working example. Almost is because there is no way to get the name of the test while iterating. But it can be achieved if the name is passed as a parameter to the unit test function. Unfortunately I was distracted in the middle an now I am away from that computer...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting with a macro-based approach, you might be interested in a solution built around X macros.  It would be a bit ugly, and a lot idiosyncratic, but it could do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Test definitions
#define TESTS \
  X(addition,  ASSERT_EQ(1 + 2, 3) ) \
  X(mult_fail, ASSERT_EQ(42, 6 * 9))

// Helper macros    
#define ASSERT_EQ(left, right) \
    do {return (left) == (right);} while(0)

// declare test functions
#define X(name, body) int test_##name(void) { body; }
TESTS
#undef X

int main(void) {
    // run tests
    #define X(name, ignored) \
      printf("%s\t%s\n", #name, test_##name() ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    TESTS
    #undef X
}
```

To add, remove, or modify tests, you just modify the definition of macro `TESTS`; the preprocessor generates everything else you need from that.

Answer (score -2):

There are some quirky ways to enumerate functions in an executable file (kind of "reflection" in pure c) or clever placement of function pointers in a special data section, etc.

A common advice is not to reinvent the wheel.  Google for existing unit test frameworks, pick one, use it, enjoy.

Comment: *how* the wheel works is what this site is all about! It is not about common advices